# what did he mean ? 8! elements in the symmetry group of the cube?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry

This question concerns a cube $C$ and its symmetry group $G$.

(i) Let $X$ represent any object, and denote by $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ the group of symmetries of
$X$. Show that the subset $S \subset \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ consisting of all symmetries of $X$ which
fix a particular point $x_0 ∈ X$, that is
$S = \{\sigma \in \operatorname{Sym}(X) \mid \sigma(x_0) = x_0\}$,
is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$.

(ii) Now consider the case $X = C$. Choose a corner $c_0$ of the cube $C$ and consider
the subset H of $G$ which fixes the point at $c_0$. By considering the symmetries of
the cube, identify the order of this subgroup.

The question goes on to ask what do the cosets of $H$ in $G$ represent and then by using Lagrange calculate the order of $G$.

My question is this. I was under the impression that the symmetry group of the cube had 48 elements and was isomorphic to $S_4\times \Bbb Z_2$ after a meeting with my lecturer today he told me this assumption was overly simplistic and that in fact there were 8! elements in G as in the case of $S_8$ and that it was not isomorphic to $S_4 \times \Bbb Z_2$ because this didn't have enough elements. I can't picture this and have only found contradictory answers on the internet . Did I misunderstand him ? I really need someone to explain to me what he meant !

Comment: Your lecturer gave you bad information. The symmetry group of the cube *should be* isomorphic to $S_4$, which you can see by letting $G$ act on the $4$ diagonals of the cube.

Comment: To get $8!$ you would need to be able to permute all $8$ vertices freely.  But a cube has more fixed structure than this

Comment: For $S_8$ see [Symmetric group on a set of size $8$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S8) and compare with [The isometries of the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry#The_isometries_of_the_cube):  "The cube has $48$ isometries (symmetry elements), forming the symmetry group isomorphic to $S_4 \times C_2$."

Comment: BTW, to see that $|G|=24$, fix a corner, $c_0$, of the cube and adjacent face. Any $g\in G$  must send $c_0$ to another corner, say $c_1$ ($8$ choices), and the face adjacent to $c_0$ must be sent to a face adjacent to $c_1$ ($3$ choices). This gives a total of $8\times 3=24$ symmetries of the cube.

Comment: yes this makes much more sense. I guess I must have misunderstood him or perhaps him me when i asked. Just a small additional question. are the cosets of H rotations about the lines connecting opposite edges of which there are 6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were $8!$ elements, then the symmetry group of the cube would be isomorphic to $S_8$. However, if we label the vertices $\{ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h \}$ and assume that $a$ and $e$ are at opposing corners, then clearly the permutation $(\, a\;\, e\, )$ that swaps $a$ and $e$ but keeps the other vertices fixed is invalid. So there are at most $8! - 1$ elements in the symmetry group $\Rightarrow$ it is not isomorphic to $S_8.$

Comment: I guess I must have misunderstood him or perhaps him me when i asked. Just a small additional question. are the cosets of H rotations about the lines connecting opposite edges of which there are 6 ?

Comment: I don't know off hand if there is anything deeper, but suppose that $h \in H$ fixes the vertex $a.$ First note that the only two such symmetries are the $120$ and $240$ degree rotations of the cube about the axis through $a$ and the vertex at the opposite corner of the cube. Then the (left) cosets of H are the group elements obtained by performing one of these rotations followed by a symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

The group $H$ has order $3$ for direct symmetries and $6$ if reflections are allowed. The easiest way to see this is that it must permute the vertices adjacent to $x_0$.

As for the cosets of $H$ there is a very simple geometric description. Whether or not reflections are allowed $H$ has index $8$ in the whole group, so you expect $8$ cosets. Suppose $Ha=Hb$ then $Hab^{-1}=H$ and $ab^{-1}\in H$ - that is very basic for any coset. But think about what it means geometrically in terms of the special point $x_0$.